# Magento Configurable Swatches Product Attributes showing "Yes" and "No"

Tags: magento, attributes, product, configurable

In my admin configuration for Configurable Swatches, under product attributes it is listed only "Yes" and "No" as option. I would expect it will list at least "Color" attribute as I have set it up via Manage Attributes.

Please have a look at below snapshot.

[image: Configurable Swatches]

Any solution?

Answer (score 2):

I manage to fix this issue. Apparently during installation quite a few .php files in **app\code\core\Mage\ConfigurableSwatches\Model** wasn't copied correctly. For example, select.php becomes a folder name instead of a PHP file (I don't know why this happened).

So what I did is just to delete the whole content of Model folder and copy from the Magento installation folder.

Comment: Boss! This had me stumped for ages!